# How to use SVG code converted to Raphaël JS on a web page?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have seen several threads that adress this question but nothing that really solves my problem. I have a SVG file with Finland counties.. What I want to do is map like this: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html.

I converted the SVG file to Raphael JS in here http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php and I'm tryig to sink that converted code into html page, but it just doesn't seem to work.. The question is why it isn't working..? Everything is supposed to be correct but it just don't draw anything. I also tryed to make exactly the same code as in raphael australia with those different paths from the map of Finland though (and tryed dirrerent converters as well).. But still nothing..

I'm pretty new with JavaScript and I have studyed and spended a lot of time with this SVG file as well.. so I'm getting little bit frustrated.. Can someone please help me..? I post the code on here under:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Raphaël - Finland</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#canvas {   height: 480px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; width: 640px; }
</style>
 <script src="raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.onload = function () {
paper.setStart();
pohj_pohjanmaa=paper.path('M 148.9 256.5 L 149.8 256.1 L 150.6 256.8 L 150.6 257.7 L 148.7 258.4 L 146.9 257.2 L 145.4 257.6 L 146.4 261 L 145.1 261.9 L 143.5 260.9 L 141.8 261.4 L 140.3 257.7 L 141.2 256.1 L 146.2 254.9 L 147.6 256.5Z');

pohj_pohjanmaa.attr({'stroke-width':'1.9','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke':'none','stroke-opacity':'1'});

lappi=paper.path('M 215.6 213.7 L 218.3 212.3 L 221 213.1 L 221.9 212.4 L 221.8 209.9 L 219.9 208.6 L 220 206 L 221.4 205.7 L 222.1 201 L 219.3 199.9 L 217.4 195.8 L 218.1 193.1 L 220.4 192.2 L 220.3 189.7 L 231.4 192.3 L 238.2 191.4 L 236.4 186.6 L 226.8 170.3 L 227.9 166.6 L 242.6 139 L 243.2 132.2 L 236.2 127.1 L 229.1 112.6 L 218.3 108.2 L 214.6 92.9 L 219 85.1 L 219.9 78.1 L 218.7 76.1 L 213.8 76.1 L 221.9 69.3 L 220.3 63.9 L 220.9 58.8 L 228.6 48.7 L 224.2 37.5 L 211.1 31 L 210.8 28.2 L 206.8 25.7 L 202.7 19.9 L 200.3 21.4 L 198 20.6 L 196.4 23 L 190 28 L 182.6 26.1 L 178.4 27.6 L 175.8 33.8 L 171.4 37.7 L 169.2 41.1 L 170.1 43.5 L 168.6 46.1 L 165.9 61.8 L 166.5 71.1 L 165 76.4 L 161.9 75.6 L 159.1 77.3 L 155.4 82.8 L 155.8 88.2 L 153.2 88.1 L 152.3 90 L 148.7 85.6 L 142.1 82.7 L 135.9 78.1 L 132.8 79.8 L 131.1 82.7 L 127 84.2 L 122.6 86.1 L 121.6 84 L 116.8 83.5 L 112.2 80.1 L 109.5 81.3 L 109.8 76.1 L 99.3 54.8 L 93.1 52.7 L 89.3 54.6 L 86.7 57.7 L 88.2 61.7 L 87.4 64.4 L 82.5 60.6 L 79 64 L 83.5 69.7 L 83.8 73.7 L 87.2 74.6 L 92.1 84.8 L 95.6 85.9 L 96.9 89.1 L 100.3 90.8 L 101.6 94.7 L 106.5 95.8 L 113 98.8 L 120 105.3 L 120.1 109.6 L 121 112.2 L 123.1 111.9 L 124 116.1 L 128 120.3 L 126.3 122.2 L 125 124.4 L 125 127.2 L 125.2 135.7 L 122.9 141.5 L 124.6 144.6 L 128.8 145.4 L 127.7 147.7 L 128.5 150.5 L 125 152.3 L 124.8 157 L 131.9 173.5 L 129.3 176.4 L 128.8 184.8 L 126.1 187.1 L 125.4 189.5 L 124.5 192.2 L 125.2 194.7 L 124.5 196.5 L 125.6 202.4 L 128.7 205.3 L 128.8 208.4 L 131.3 212.5 L 131.6 215.5 L 133.1 219.6 L 133.1 222.9 L 134.8 222.7 L 136 220.8 L 137.4 222.6 L 140.5 223.7 L 141.5 225.2 L 140.4 227.5 L 141.2 228.4 L 142.7 227.4 L 143.3 229.3 L 144.6 229.2 L 145.6 228.3 L 147.7 228.6 L 148.9 230.3 L 150.3 230.1 L 151.2 231.1 L 151.2 231.2 L 153.4 228.9 L 156.6 227.3 L 157.1 225.1 L 165.1 225.5 L 172 221.1 L 172.6 225.6 L 186.3 226.8 L 191 225.2 L 197.4 214.9 L 199.4 215.8 L 201 215.1 L 203 220.2 L 213.2 221.8 L 217.6 219.9 L 217.8 217Z');

lappi.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

pohj_pohjanmaa2=paper.path('M 244.1 234.8 L 245 232 L 243.4 229.3 L 247.6 226.5 L 250.5 226.2 L 249.2 217.1 L 244.8 204.4 L 241 199 L 238.2 191.4 L 231.4 192.3 L 220.3 189.7 L 220.4 192.2 L 218.1 193.1 L 217.4 195.8 L 219.3 199.9 L 222.1 201 L 221.4 205.7 L 220 206 L 219.9 208.6 L 221.8 209.9 L 221.9 212.4 L 221 213.1 L 218.3 212.3 L 215.6 213.7 L 217.8 217 L 217.6 219.9 L 213.2 221.8 L 203 220.2 L 201 215.1 L 199.4 215.8 L 197.4 214.9 L 191 225.2 L 186.3 226.8 L 172.6 225.6 L 172 221.1 L 165.1 225.5 L 157.1 225.1 L 156.6 227.3 L 153.4 228.9 L 151.2 231.1 C 151.3 231.2 151.4 231.3 151.5 231.4 L 151.6 233.4 L 152.7 233.4 L 153.3 232.7 L 156.2 237.7 L 156 239.6 L 154.8 240.9 L 154.8 243.1 L 153.8 244.2 L 154.7 245.7 L 154.6 250.4 L 153.3 252.2 L 154 253.6 L 155.9 254.7 L 156.6 256.1 L 157.1 259.2 L 158.5 260.7 L 158.4 261.5 L 157.5 261.5 L 155.3 259.7 L 153.3 259.6 L 152.9 260.6 L 153.1 261.8 L 156 264.8 L 156.6 266.5 L 155.9 267.2 L 154.5 267.1 L 154.2 265.5 L 151.3 263.8 L 148.6 263.8 L 147.1 264.9 L 143.9 265 L 142.8 265.9 L 142.2 267.1 L 140.4 267.3 L 139.6 271.2 L 136.7 273.2 L 135.2 279.7 L 133.3 281.2 L 133.2 282.2 L 130.6 283.9 L 127.5 287.2 L 127.1 288.3 L 125.9 290.2 L 125.9 292.4 L 125 292.9 L 123.8 292.1 L 122.5 294.1 L 121.4 295 L 120.3 296.7 L 118.8 299 L 118.6 302.5 L 121.6 306.6 L 123.4 306.6 L 124.8 307.8 L 126 307.2 L 124.7 305.4 L 125.9 303.1 L 129 302.5 L 130.4 308.2 L 132 309 L 132.7 312.1 L 135 313 L 137.4 320.4 L 146.7 331.7 L 149.3 331.4 L 150.3 325.3 L 152.5 324.4 L 159.5 329.2 L 163 329.2 L 164.5 330.4 L 165.8 333.3 L 170.4 333.2 L 172.8 326.4 L 174.1 325.6 L 173 314.3 L 180.4 307.4 L 185.6 305.7 L 184 303.6 L 184 293.1 L 181.6 291.5 L 179.9 291.8 L 177.7 289.9 L 178 287.8 L 176.9 285.3 L 174.9 284 L 178.7 280.2 L 180.7 279.6 L 181.4 277.2 L 185.7 275.1 L 187.2 270.8 L 191.1 268.9 L 191.2 267.8 L 195.8 268.9 L 196.6 266.6 L 196.2 260.4 L 193.7 258.3 L 195.6 255.2 L 199.8 255.2 L 201.9 253.5 L 204.4 253.9 L 206.5 255.3 L 207.4 249.7 L 209.6 248.3 L 220.5 246.4 L 221 241.4 L 227.1 238.5 L 228.4 239.5 L 230.6 238.9 L 232.5 234.9 L 233.4 235.6 L 238.6 235.9 L 244.1 234.8Z');
pohj_pohjanmaa2.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

kainuu=paper.path('M 250.7 277.9 L 252.4 276.5 L 252.5 273.5 L 250.9 271.5 L 251.6 269.1 L 244 267.5 L 241.8 259 L 242.6 256 L 245.5 255 L 246.6 252.7 L 245.5 251.3 L 246.8 248.6 L 245.6 247.2 L 241.7 246.9 L 243.3 241.3 L 243.7 236.5 L 244.2 234.7 L 238.6 235.9 L 233.4 235.6 L 232.5 234.9 L 230.6 238.9 L 228.4 239.5 L 227.1 238.5 L 221 241.4 L 220.5 246.4 L 209.6 248.3 L 207.4 249.7 L 206.5 255.3 L 204.3 253.9 L 201.9 253.5 L 199.8 255.2 L 195.6 255.1 L 193.7 258.3 L 196.2 260.4 L 196.6 266.6 L 195.8 268.9 L 191.2 267.8 L 191.1 268.9 L 187.2 270.8 L 185.7 275.1 L 181.4 277.2 L 180.7 279.6 L 178.7 280.2 L 174.9 284 L 176.9 285.3 L 178 287.8 L 177.7 289.9 L 179.9 291.8 L 181.6 291.5 L 184 293.1 L 184 303.6 L 185.6 305.7 L 192.1 308.1 L 199.7 308.7 L 209 314.6 L 215 321.6 L 219 312.3 L 229.1 314.2 L 244.1 311.5 L 247.3 319.5 L 249.3 317.2 L 253.1 317.6 L 252.8 317.3 L 257.6 313.9 L 262.8 300.5 L 261.2 293.1 L 253.1 287.6 L 250.7 281.3Z');
kainuu.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

etela_karjala=paper.path('M 225.9 363.5 L 224 364 L 226.6 369.9 L 228.5 370.5 L 232.6 374.3 L 232.9 375.9 L 235.1 377.7 L 234.2 379.8 L 236.3 381.3 L 238.4 380.1 L 239.6 381.6 L 239.6 384.1 L 242.4 388.7 L 244.1 397.8 L 247 399 L 248.1 401.7 L 247.2 402.9 L 248.9 406.3 L 247 411.8 L 260.4 404.6 L 263.1 401.8 L 269 391.3 L 273.4 384.7 L 276.2 383.6 L 281.5 373.8 L 287.7 354.1 L 285.9 349.5 L 280.6 345.2 L 278.9 339.3 L 275.1 336.7 L 270.4 332.9 L 263.7 329.9 L 261 326.1 L 253 317.6 L 249.3 317.3 L 247.2 319.5 L 244.1 311.5 L 229.1 314.2 L 219 312.4 L 216.6 317.8 L 219.6 321 L 221.9 321.2 L 222.5 326 L 223.8 327 L 222.8 328.5 L 223.4 334 L 225.7 335.3 L 225.7 338.6 L 223.7 342.3 L 225.3 343.8 L 228.8 351.1 L 233.6 353.6 L 230.4 355.9 L 233 359.5 L 230.3 363.3 L 226.5 361.7Z');

etela_karjala.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

etela_savo=paper.path('M 173.8 428.4 L 173.9 430.3 L 176.1 432.3 L 177.4 432.5 L 177.6 434.9 L 179.2 434.2 L 181.6 438 L 183.9 436.9 L 183.9 434.5 L 186.9 434.6 L 186.9 438.6 L 191.1 440.7 L 193.5 439.9 L 196.8 439.1 L 199.2 435 L 201.5 434.8 L 202.9 431.9 L 205.6 432 L 207.1 430.1 L 209.6 430.6 L 217 429.9 L 220.8 425.2 L 222 422.4 L 224.1 424.1 L 229.7 424 L 230.4 421.5 L 235 421.7 L 239.6 420.2 L 242.4 415.5 L 246.1 414.3 L 246.9 411.9 L 247 411.8 L 248.9 406.3 L 247.2 402.9 L 248.1 401.7 L 247 399 L 244.1 397.8 L 242.4 388.7 L 239.6 384.1 L 239.6 381.6 L 238.4 380.1 L 236.3 381.3 L 234.2 379.8 L 235.1 377.7 L 232.9 375.9 L 232.6 374.3 L 228.5 370.5 L 226.6 369.9 L 225.1 370.3 L 221.2 374.2 L 219.2 374.2 L 219.2 378.6 L 217.4 378.4 L 216 380.7 L 217.6 381.9 L 216.7 383.8 L 219.4 383.7 L 219.5 386 L 222 385.4 L 225.5 389.7 L 224.4 392.3 L 217.5 389.6 L 213.2 390.1 L 210.6 387.8 L 206.8 387.6 L 204.6 383.8 L 197 377.1 L 193.3 379.6 L 191.7 377.6 L 188.5 378.4 L 187.7 379.6 L 185.5 378.7 L 183.1 379.9 L 181.5 381 L 184 383.8 L 181.8 384.6 L 180.5 390.1 L 177.9 388.7 L 174.2 391 L 172.1 395.2 L 175.4 401.3 L 174.5 402.8 L 175.2 410.9 L 178.4 415.6 L 177.6 418.5 L 174.8 417.6 L 174.4 418.6 L 172.9 422.6 L 172.4 427.4Z');
etela_savo.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

pohj_savo=paper.path('M 222.8 328.5 L 223.8 327 L 222.5 326 L 221.9 321.2 L 219.6 321 L 216.6 317.8 L 215 321.6 L 209 314.6 L 199.7 308.7 L 192.1 308.1 L 185.6 305.7 L 180.4 307.4 L 173 314.3 L 174.1 325.6 L 172.8 326.4 L 170.4 333.2 L 169.4 337.1 L 171 339.3 L 171.5 347.2 L 174.5 351.5 L 172.7 352.7 L 174.1 354.1 L 172.9 356.1 L 168.6 356.7 L 174.8 364.5 L 176.7 364.1 L 179.3 368.1 L 180 372.4 L 177.1 375.6 L 177.1 376.9 L 180.5 379 L 182.1 378.8 L 183.1 379.9 L 185.5 378.7 L 187.7 379.6 L 188.5 378.4 L 191.7 377.6 L 193.3 379.6 L 197 377.1 L 204.6 383.8 L 206.8 387.6 L 210.6 387.8 L 213.2 390.1 L 217.5 389.6 L 224.4 392.3 L 225.5 389.7 L 222 385.4 L 219.5 386 L 219.4 383.7 L 216.7 383.8 L 217.6 381.9 L 216 380.7 L 217.4 378.4 L 219.2 378.6 L 219.2 374.2 L 221.2 374.2 L 225.1 370.3 L 226.6 369.9 L 224 364 L 225.9 363.5 L 226.5 361.7 L 230.3 363.3 L 233 359.5 L 230.4 355.9 L 233.6 353.6 L 228.8 351.1 L 225.3 343.8 L 223.7 342.3 L 225.7 338.6 L 225.7 335.3 L 223.4 334Z');

pohj_savo.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

kanta_hame=paper.path('M 105.8 445.3 L 103.7 443.7 L 102.1 444.6 L 102.1 445.9 L 103.9 447 L 102.7 449.8 L 100.5 450.3 L 100.3 452.3 L 101.6 453.8 L 100.5 454.7 L 100.7 456.5 L 104.5 458.4 L 107.3 457 L 112.7 461.1 L 117.4 462.6 L 124.2 463.8 L 125.1 465.7 L 126.7 464.5 L 128.3 465.3 L 128.8 466.8 L 132.9 466 L 132.8 463.8 L 133.9 462.2 L 136.6 462.6 L 141 462 L 142.5 461.4 L 145.5 462.3 L 145.3 460.9 L 147.3 459.5 L 145.9 458.5 L 144.6 459.7 L 145 457.8 L 146.6 457.3 L 145.9 455.7 L 144.9 453.6 L 146.5 452.3 L 143.8 449.1 L 144.9 444.6 L 149.1 442.1 L 148.7 436.5 L 146.5 434.8 L 144.8 435.6 L 145.3 433.8 L 141.6 432.3 L 138.9 433.5 L 137.2 431.7 L 136.4 433.6 L 132.6 432.1 L 128.4 435.5 L 127.6 435 L 127.1 435.8 L 127.2 436.7 L 127.7 437.3 L 126.3 438.9 L 116 442.8 L 116.7 447.7 L 115.9 448.4 L 112.8 445.1 L 108.3 446.8 L 106.2 446.8Z');

kanta_hame.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

paijat_hame=paper.path('M 164.2 410.7 L 167 412.1 L 170.1 416.9 L 174.5 418.7 L 173 422.7 L 172.4 427.5 L 173.9 428.5 L 174 430.4 L 176.1 432.4 L 177.4 432.6 L 177.6 434.9 L 176.2 435.7 L 175 438.8 L 171.9 440.9 L 168.6 440.9 L 168 442.9 L 168.9 444.8 L 169.6 448.2 L 167.7 448.1 L 166.9 449.6 L 169.3 450.7 L 168.1 452.9 L 168.2 455.4 L 170.3 456.8 L 170.6 459.1 L 171.2 459.4 L 171 461.5 L 169 462.6 L 167.1 460.9 L 164.1 461.5 L 164 459.5 L 162 460.9 L 160.7 460.7 L 156.5 462 L 155.5 460.7 L 155.2 460.8 L 154.2 457 L 153.5 456.3 L 151.1 458.8 L 148 455.1 L 145.9 455.7 L 144.9 453.6 L 146.5 452.3 L 143.8 449.1 L 144.9 444.6 L 149.1 442.1 L 148.7 436.5 L 146.5 434.8 L 144.8 435.6 L 145.3 433.8 L 141.6 432.3 L 141.2 424.4 L 142.5 425.2 L 154.1 424.1 L 156.4 415.7 L 159.9 414.1 L 161.8 415Z');

paijat_hame.attr({'stroke':'#000000','stroke-width':'1.88','stroke-miterlimit':'4','fill':'#000000','stroke-opacity':'1'});

ahvenanmaa=paper.path('M 47.7 465.5 L 48.9 464.8 L 50.1 466.6 L 49.7 468.3 L 48.5 468.9 L 47.5 466.7Z M 49.9 469.4 L 51.5 468.1 L 52.5 469.3 L 52.1 471.5 L 51.3 472.2 L 50.3 471.6Z M 47.9 472.4 L 46.7 472.8 L 45.9 471.9 L 46.4 470.4 L 47.9 471Z M 44.4 472.6 L 43.3 472.9 L 42.9 472.4 L 42.9 472.3 L 43.3 471 L 44.2 470.4 L 44.9 471.1Z M 45.7 475.8 L 44.2 477.2 L 43.5 476.7 L 43.3 476 L 43.3 474.7 L 44.6 474.1 L 45.4 475.2Z M 42.5 477.7 L 42.7 478.7 L 41.2 478.7 L 40.7 476.9 L 41.2 476.1 L 42.2 476.3 L 42.5 477.1Z M 41.2 479.6 L 42.1 481.6 L 41.9 482 L 41.8 482.8 L 40.1 482.7 L 39.7 480.9 L 38.9 480 L 39.7 478.7Z M 36.3 471.5 L 33 471.2 L 33 470.2 L 33.9 469.5 L 36.3 470.7Z M 34.5 473.3 L 35.3 472.6 L 35.9 473.5 L 35.4 474.6 L 36.2 475.8 L 35 477.5 L 34.2 477.5 L 34.3 475.3 L 33.4 474.3Z M 37.9 484.5 L 38.7 485.4 L 37.7 486.6 L 34.6 487.5 L 32.3 487.5 L 31.9 486.7 L 33.9 485 L 35.1 484.1Z M 36.1 482.3 L 36.8 481.5 L 37.6 481.7 L 38.6 482.7 L 38.7 483.4 L 36.9 483.2Z M 31.5 481.6 L 32 482.7 L 30.4 482.7 L 30.1 480.4 L 31.6 478.7 L 32.1 478.8 L 32.4 480Z M 30.2 482.7 L 30.2 483.7 L 29.7 484.8 L 30.6 485.7 L 30.4 486.9 L 28.9 487.9 L 28.6 486.3 L 27.6 486.5 L 26.9 484.9 L 24.8 483.4 L 23 483.8 L 22.8 482.3 L 22.1 481.4 L 20.6 481.2 L 19.8 480.3 L 19.5 478.4 L 18.1 476.8 L 17.1 476.8 L 16.3 476.6 L 15.9 478 L 14.8 478.1 L 14 476.3 L 14.4 474.3 L 13.6 473.5 L 14.1 472.2 L 17 470.9 L 18.3 471.4 L 19.7 471.1 L 20.8 469.7 L 22 470.5 L 21.7 472.7 L 22.6 473 L 23.4 472.1 L 23.1 471.4 L 23.1 470.5 L 22.4 469.3 L 20.3 469 L 22.2 466.5 L 24 465.7 L 26.4 468 L 28.5 468.4 L 29.5 470 L 30.8 470.6 L 31 472.1 L 32.5 474 L 31.3 477.2 L 28.7 477.6 L 27.1 475.8 L 26.1 475.7 L 25.2 477.2 L 26.7 478.3 L 25.4 481.3 L 25.8 481.8 L 27 481.8 L 27.8 481.3Z M 44.4 490.4 L 46.4 489.5 L 47 489.9 L 48.2 490.5 L 47.8 491 L 47.6 491.8 L 46.7 491.8 L 45.9 493 L 44 491.5Z');

ahvenanmaa.attr({'fill':'#000000','stroke':'none'});
/*
...and so on..
*/
var st = paper.setFinish();
/*********************************************************************************
The below lines use the set to transform your SVG to:
(1)Translate (Move) your image to the top left of the paper.
(2)Scale your vector image to fit inside the the paper.
Remove this comment and alter or remove the code below it.
*********************************************************************************/
var translate='t'+(-1*st.getBBox().x)+','+(-1*st.getBBox().y);
st.transform(translate+'s0.91,0.91,0,0');
/*********************************************************************************
The below lines use the set to add event handlers.
As you mouseover the above code window vectors they change colour.
If your trying to locate a path, click on the vector image above...
Remove this comment and alter or remove the code below it.
*********************************************************************************/
function callback(member)
{
member.mouseover(function (e) {  this.ofill=this.attr('fill');this.attr({fill:'#ffffff'}); });
member.mouseout(function (e) { this.attr({fill:this.ofill}); });
member.click(function (e) { var thisPath=this.attr('path');alert('You just clicked on Element #'+this.id+'.To help you find it in the code its path starts with......'+thisPath); });
}
st.forEach(callback);
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="canvas">
<div id="paper"></div>
<div id="pohj_pohjanmaa"></div>
<div id="lappi"></div>
<div id="pohj_pohjanmaa2"></div>
<div id="kainuu"></div>
<div id="etela-karjala"></div>
<div id="etela-savo"></div>
<div id="pohj_savo"></div>
<div id="kanta_hame"></div>
<div id="paijat_hame"></div>
<div id="ahvenanmaa"></div>
<div id="varsinais-suomi"></div>
<div id="etela_pohjanmaa"></div>
<div id="keski_suomi"></div>
<div id="pirkanmaa"></div>
<div id="satakunta"></div>
<div id="kymenlaakso"></div>
<div id="keski_pohjanmaa"></div>
<div id="uusimaa"></div>
<div id="etela_karjala"></div>
<div id="pohjanmaa"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest thing that the converter did was pull that the path data from the SVG files that you fed it.  My suggestion is to use that data, but with other code.

In order to simplify and keep things as [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible, you will want to create two objects.  One will contain path data for each county and the other will contain counties attribute data.  With these objects you can run a simple for loop and build your map that way. I hope the following code helps.

*note that **pathData** represents the path strings such as 'M 192.9 S 9494 ...290 Z'*

**Javascript**

```
//create Raphael county map
var countyMap = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);

//create county map object to hold extracted path data
var finlandCounty = {
    pohj_pohjanmaa:'pathData',
    lappi: 'pathData',
    kainuu: 'pathData',
    etela_karjala: 'pathData',
    etela_savo: 'pathData'
};

//create attribute object
var countyAttr = {
    'stroke-width':1.9,
    'stroke-miterlimit':4,
    fill:'#000000',
    stroke:'none',
    'stroke-opacity':1
};

//loop through county object list and create the map
for (var county in finlandCounty) {
    county = countyMap.path(county).attr(countyAttr);

    //set click event
    county.click(function(){
        alert('You just clicked on Element '+this.id);
    }

    //set hover event
    county.hover(
        function () {
            this.animate({fill: "#ffffff"}, 400);
        },function () {
            this.animate({fill:countyAttr.fill}, 400);
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="canvas></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.. (Alltaught the code still isn't drawing anything to page).. The structure of the code is much better like that.. There was some error at the end (at "county.hover(function(){..." line), I'll have to look at it more later..cause this is quite big file, it takes a long time to make changes to this..

Comment: Although, I'm not entirely sure what your error was I made a change to the hover function.  I think it should work now. Let me know if it does.

Comment: Okay.. solved..! I finally get it to work.. :) just tooked those path data values from SVG converted to JS file and put those values to the code similar to http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html.. And it somehow started to work.. Awesome..! Now I have interactive map of Finland counties..!

Comment: Congratulations, there is a great feeling in creating a map for a country.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your code is that I don't see anywhere where you actually create the paper object. You simply use the variable `paper` assuming that it's a Raphael paper object but from your code it actually looks like it's `undefined`.

You need to create a paper object:

```
var paper = Raphael('paper');
```

If you look at Jon Black's answer he calls his paper `countyMap` and it's initialized on this line:

```
var countyMap = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
```

The paper doesn't have to be called `paper` and the variable `paper` is not a special magic variable that will automatically create a Raphael paper object. You need to create the paper object yourself and you can name it anything you like.

I strongly encourage that you write your code by using another name (like `canvas` for example) instead of `paper` for the Raphael paper object just to get comfortable with how things really work and avoid confusing yourself.